# Loop through API multiple parameters

Tags: json, python-3.x, if-statement, url, python-requests

I have the website's API documentation http://json-homework.task-sss.krasilnikov.spb.ru/docs/9f66a575a6cfaaf7e43177317461d057 and I am to find all the users who have studied in schools in certain city (id of which is 2). By running this code(`all_users` is a list with main info about users from the previous task):

```
school=[]
for user in all_users:
        user_id=user.get('id') 
        url = f'http://json-homework.task-sss.krasilnikov.spb.ru/api/user/get?api_key=9f66a575a6cfaaf7e43177317461d057&user_id={user_id}&fields=schools'
        data = rq.get(url)
        school=school+json.loads(data.text)["response"]
school
```

I get such kind of data(here is a small part of the output with many fields filled):

```
 {'id': 136840302,
  'first_name': 'Marina',
  'last_name': 'Kushnir',
  'is_closed': False,
  'schools': [{'id': '352496',
    'country': 1,
    'city': 57,
    'name': 'Лицей ИГУ',
    'year_from': 2015,
    'year_to': 2019,
    'class': '',
    'type': 2,
    'type_str': 'Lyceum'}]},
```

So I have a parameter 'city' enclosed in the parameter 'schools', and I need to extract only those users who have this parameter `'city': 2`. I aldo tried this code:

```
school=[]
for user in all_users:
    user_id=user.get('id') 
    url = f'http://json-homework.task-sss.krasilnikov.spb.ru/api/user/get?api_key=9f66a575a6cfaaf7e43177317461d057&user_id={user_id}&fields=schools'
    data = rq.get(url)
    school=school+json.loads(data.text)["response"]
school_norm=json_normalize(school)
schools = school_norm.get('schools')
school2=[]
for i in schools:
        if "'city' : 2" in i:
            school2.append(json.loads(data.text)["response"])
sch=pd.DataFrame(school2)
```

but it does not accept such condition `if "'city' : 2" in i:`. So how can I do this task?

My code from first task is

```
all_users = []
for page in range(1,42):
    url=f'http://json-homework.task-sss.krasilnikov.spb.ru/api/groups/getmembers?api_key=9f66a575a6cfaaf7e43177317461d057&group_id=4508123&page={page}'
    data=rq.get(url)
    all_users = all_users + json.loads(data.text)["response"]
json_normalize(all_users)
group_data = pd.DataFrame(all_users, columns=['id','first_name','last_name']) 
group_data = group_data.sort_values('id')
group_data = group_data.set_index('id')
group_data
```

and the output: [image: DataFrame]
So in the output of my abovewritten task I need to get similar to this dataframe, but only with those people who have school city id=2, as I explained before

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable. Though when I checked it through `.dtypes`, the column 'schools' had object type, not float

Comment: I think I have a way to do, but not sure what your dataframe is supposed to look like. Given your data above, can you edit the question and show what the df should look like?

Comment: edited and added a little from previous related task

Comment: One more question: in your data above, "Marina" has two ids: one seems to be her own, and one seems to be her school's id. Which id goes into your df?

Comment: the first one, I only need 'city':2 from 'schools'

Answer (score 1):

The following is a little convoluted, but it should get you at least close enough to where you want to go. Note that it assumes that your data is in valid json format (which in your question is not; you'll have to deal with it separately - [see this for one option to fix malformed json.](https://hjson.github.io/)

Anyway, given that, I personally feel the best way to handle this type of question is by using jsonpath for python. So here goes:

Let's assume your data consists of two (valid json) one of which meets the condition that city id is 2, and the other doesn't:

```
schls ="""
[
  {
    "id": 136840302,
    "first_name": "Marina",
    "last_name": "Kushnir",
    "is_closed": "False,",
    "schools": [
      {
        "id": "352496",
        "country": 1,
        "city": 57,
        "name": "Лицей ИГУ",
        "year_from": 2015,
        "year_to": 2019,
        "class": "",
        "type": 2,
        "type_str": "Lyceum"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 5555555555555,
    "first_name": "Marino",
    "last_name": "Kush",
    "is_closed": "False,",
    "schools": [
      {
        "id": "355556",
        "country": 1,
        "city": 2,
        "name": "Лице ИГ",
        "year_from": 2016,
        "year_to": 2018,
        "class": "",
        "type": 4,
        "type_str": "Lyceu"
      }
    ]
  }
]
"""
```

Let's process the data:

```
import pandas as pd
import json
from jsonpath_ng import jsonpath, parse

data = json.loads(schls)
jsn_search = parse('$..schools') #this is your search string; looking for info in the "schools" entry
match = jsn_search.find(data) #search for the search string in the loaded json
schools = []
for m in match:
    if m.context.value.get('schools')[0].get('city')== 2: #this is your condition!
        schools.append(m.context.value) #condition met; append all surrounding info to list
df=pd.DataFrame(schools)
sch = df.drop(['is_closed' , 'schools'] , axis='columns')
sch
```

Output:

```
        id      first_name  last_name
0   5555555555555   Marino  Kush
```

Comment: I get `IndexError: list index out of range` on this line `if m.context.value.get('schools')[0].get('city')== 2:`

Comment: @DianaPavlova - Is the error on your actual data or the data I posted in the answer?

Comment: @DianaPavlova I tried it again and worked fine on my side. Try `print(len(match))` and let me know if it outputs `2`. If not, you have some typo somewhere, either in pasting the data or in the statements.

Comment: hmm it outputs 1

Comment: @DianaPavlova  see demo here: https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/ipython/ipython-in-depth/7e5ce96cc9251083979efdfc393425f1229a4a68

Comment: oh sorry, your code does work, but I don't understand now how to include all the data about all users here instead of your two..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209216/discussion-between-jack-fleeting-and-diana-pavlova).